# jQuery toggle not working on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I resize the window, the toggle part is not working, I had to refresh the page again(keeping the window in the resized state) and it works fine.

bodyClass() part is working fine, just not the menu() part.

Please help :)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function menu(){

        var memberAreaWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        if( memberAreaWidth <= 900 ){

            jQuery('.memebers-menu').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('.memebers-header-logo span').click(function(){

                jQuery('.memebers-menu').toggle();

            });         
        }


    }

    function bodyClass(){           

        var memberAreaWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        if( memberAreaWidth > 900 ){
            jQuery('body').addClass('fullwidth');
        }else{
            jQuery('body').removeClass('fullwidth');
        }

    }

    jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(){

        menu();
        bodyClass();

    });

});
```

Comment: After setting the memebers-menu element to display none using  jQuery('.memebers-menu').css('display', 'none'); How can you click it?

Comment: Try placing `windows event attachment` outside `document.ready`

Comment: It's bad practice to be binding that click event every time the browser width is resized. The JS most likely is not responding because your asking it to do too much.

Comment: @Guruorasad Rao did not work.

Comment: @magreenberg the other part i.e. bodyclass is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the click event delegation so it only happens once. The rest of the code looks fine.

```
var smallWidth = false;

jQuery('.memebers-header-logo span').click(function(){
    if (smallWidth){
        jQuery('.memebers-menu').toggle();
    }
});  

function menu(){

    var memberAreaWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if( memberAreaWidth <= 900 ){

        jQuery('.memebers-menu').css('display', 'none');
        smallWidth = true;
    } else {
        smallWidth = false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code a bit, put the event handlers outside the functions so they do not re-bind each time the function is called (which would end up with multiple event handlers firing); pass a parameter so you only have to calculate it once.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.memebers-header-logo span').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.memebers-menu').toggle();
  });
  jQuery(window).on("load resize", function() {
    var memberAreaWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    menu(memberAreaWidth);
    bodyClass(memberAreaWidth);
  });

  function menu(memberAreaWidth) {
    if (memberAreaWidth <= 900) {
      jQuery('.memebers-menu').hide();
    }
  }

  function bodyClass(memberAreaWidth) {
    if (memberAreaWidth > 900) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('fullwidth');
    } else {
      jQuery('body').removeClass('fullwidth');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If your going to simplify the code, might as well only have one function instead of two! :)

Comment: Yes but I did it this way to make the refactor simpler to understand